# detecting user closing tabs or leaving the site

Tags: javascript, authentication

I'd like to be able to tell when the user leaves the site so I can update a field in my database (particularly, a `last_visit` field in order to determine unread items for each user). However, I'm not sure how to manage the fact that sometimes, a user opens several tabs of the site, so I can't use `onbeforeunload` reliably to accomplish this goal.

Ideally, I would be able to update this field only when there is only one open tab of the site.

On the hand, maybe I could get more functionality by simply using a table to record read items for several days and assuming that threads older than that are read by default.

What do you think?

Regards

Comment: Why haven't you thought about finding a work around for `onbeforeunload` when user has multiple tabs/browsers open? you'd just have to keep a counter of tabs user has opened, update it `onbeforeunload`, if after update, the counter is 0, update last visited time. Simple. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

All I can think of is using either cookies or local storage to update the time at which they're viewing your site on each page load. This way, once they close all the tabs where your website is open, the cookie/local storage entry won't update, and you can access that value later on when they return.

So run this every time the page loads:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('lastVisit',Date.now);
```

And to grab it:

```
var lastVisit = window.localStorage.getItem('lastVisit');
```